# TypeError: AWS.Location is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, maps

im writing a code for get a route between two point from "AWS Location". My issue is that AWS does not find "Location", but "Location" is  in the documentation.

```
async function ruteador() {

        await credentials.getPromise();
        var params = {
          "DeparturePosition": [-122.7565,49.0021],
          "DestinationPosition": [-122.3394, 47.6159],
          "DistanceUnit": "Miles",
        }
        var location = new AWS.Location({region: AWS.config.region});
        location.calculateRoute(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
          else     console.log(data);           // successful response
        });

      }
```

Also when i get CognitoCredentials, "new AWS.Cognito.." it´s work

```
const credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: identityPoolId,
      });
```

documentation of aws:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Location.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Location.html#calculateRoute-property

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, can you include it in your post?

Comment: How do you import `AWS` and what is the aws sdk version that you're using ?

Comment: <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.784.0.min.js"></script> @LakshyaThakur

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: AWS.location is not a constructor
    at ruteador (test2.html:91) @jordanm

Comment: i changed aws version to <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.986.0.min.js"></script> and its works! although i found other erros @LakshyaThakur